# Saving data from multiple pages in local storage without overwriting the local storage for the other pages

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I'm using localStorage.setItem(dataToStore) to store data from two separate pages that I'm running in Firefox; both pages use Javascript. When I store the data from one page, it overwrites the data I've stored from the other page.

On my first page, I collect people's mouse clicks, saving them to local storage using localStorage.setItem(array of clicks on page 1). On the second page, I collect clicks also, saving them using localStorage.setItem(array of clicks on page 2). To retrieve the stored items, I add "console.log(localStorage.getItem)" to my Javascript functions, and open the pages in Firefox.

localStorage.getItem returns only the data for whichever page I have most recently run, so it looks as though the pages save to the same local storage file and overwrite each other. My guess is that there's a way to index the pages (using different attributes?) so that the data is stored independently for the separate functions, but I'm not sure how to do this. Any tips?